# onCreateView ListView is Empty. Items Missing

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Resolved. See singularhum's answer below.

---

I have a sliding menu option that points to a fragment. This fragment inflates a layout using `onCreateView`. I update the values of the list in `onActivityCreated` . Here is my source.

My Listview
[image: Pic]

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    this.portfolio = new Portfolio();
    this.portfolio.addCompanyNoUpdate("YHOO");

    // Specify the fragment layout file for this fragment class
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock, container, false);
    progressText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressTextView);

    // Assign our CursorAdapter
    adapter = new QuoteAdapter(getActivity(), portfolio.getQuotes());
    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     return view;
}
```

Then I have the `onActivityCreated` just doing an update.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.update();
}
```

My Update Class

```
private void update() {
    // If a network connection is available, update the stock information
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        // Start a custom task that downloads the data on another thread so the UI does not lock up
        new UpdateQuotesTask().execute(portfolio);
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise display an error message to the user
        this.progressText.setText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private Context     context;
  private List<Quote> quotes;


  public QuoteAdapter(Context c, List<Quote> quotes) {
this.context = c;
this.quotes = quotes;
}


public void addQuote(Quote q) {
this.quotes.add(q);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return this.quotes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return this.quotes.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
// We can just return a default value for this adapter
return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
MiniQuoteView miniQuoteView = new MiniQuoteView(this.context,     this.quotes.get(position));
miniQuoteView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

return miniQuoteView;
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
this.quotes.remove(position);
}
}
```

And Finally My XML as the standard listview

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/progressTextView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/none" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressTextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason my Listview turns out to be empty.
See the image.
As you can see the debugger also has some values for the adapter.
[image]

Here are the related MiniQuoteView Class and XML

http://pastebin.com/rRpRA30L 
http://pastebin.com/YajCCqdJ

Comment: Sadly my Debugger shows that the values are fetched and ready to serve into the listview

Comment: post the MiniQuoteView

Comment: So portfolio.getQuotes() contains something?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rRpRA30L - this is the miniquoteview.

Comment: Yes portfolio.GetQuotes contains the  public List<Quote> getQuotes() {
    return this.companies;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is in the `fillData` method in your `MiniQuoteView` class.

Your first `if` statement is:

```
if (this.quote == null)
```

but you do not have an `else` or `else if` statement for when the `quote` object is **not null**.

Then if you look at your second `if` statement (which reads the `quote` data and sets to views) inside your first one, it is:

```
if (this.quote.name != null)
```

which will never be true because the `quote` is null within that `if`. That is why you are not seeing anything in your list view because nothing is being set to be displayed.

So it should be something like this:

```
if (this.quote == null) {
    // displaying your not available message
} else if (this.quote.name != null){
    // your code to display the data
}
```